# Firebase messaging shows 0 messages sent

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm testing my implementation of firebase messaging with my ios react native app and sent notifications through the firebase dashboard - but it shows 0 messages sent.  I'm using this library and their sample code:

https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm

I've tried putting in the firebase messaging token directly to message my single test device, but that also sends 0 messages.

How can I debug what's going on in Firebase?  Can I see a list of registered devices somewhere?  I've configured the APN certificates both on apple and on firebase so not sure where to go next.

I get a firebase token in my app so not sure if there is anything else I need to do.

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        FCM.requestPermissions(); // for iOS
        FCM.getFCMToken().then(token => {
            saveTokenToMyProfile(token);
        });
        this.notificationListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {
            // there are two parts of notif. notif.notification contains the notification payload, notif.data contains data payload

            if(notif.opened_from_tray){
              //app is open/resumed because user clicked banner
            }

        this.refreshTokenListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.RefreshToken, (token) => {
            console.log(token)
            // fcm token may not be available on first load, catch it here
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Notification is experiencing delayes in calculating the sent count.
This should not affect the actual message delievery

https://status.firebase.google.com/

> We are experiencing delays in Firebase Notifications calculating sent
>   counts beginning at Tuesday, 2017-02-28 08:30 AM US/Pacific.
>
> Current data indicates that all users are affected by this issue.
>
> For everyone who is affected, we apologize for any inconvenience you
>   may be experiencing. We will provide an update by 02:25 AM US/Pacific
>   with current details.